# Execute code after loading content via ajax in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
boot_sections = ["123625","113231","11232","113216", ..... ];

for (var k in boot_sections) {
    $.get('/load?sectionId=' + boot_sections[k], function(data) {
        $('#sections').append(data);
    });
}
```

This is where I load stuff.

I need to add datepicker, lazyload and image preview, but I need to **wait until the loading *of all requests* has finished**.

How can I check if all the requests are done?

I tried like:

```
$('#sections:last-child').ready(function() { /* apply stuff here */ });
```

But I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well... that's not what the ready method is for, of course it didn't work. You need to use `$.when()`

```
var requestArray = [];

for (var k in boot_sections) {
    requestArray.push($.get('/load?sectionId=' + boot_sections[k], function(data) {
        $('#sections').append(data);
    }));
}

$.when.apply($,requestArray).done(function(){
    // do stuff
})
```

Also, since you're using an array, you shouldn't use a for-in loop. jQuery has a method that makes this code simpler given an array (works with objects too)

```
var requestArray = $.map(boot_sections,function(id) {
    return $.get('/load?sectionId=' + id, function(data) {
        $('#sections').append(data);
    });
}

$.when.apply($,requestArray).done(function(){
    // do stuff
})
```